# Replace 0s and forward fill from columns along the same row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I would like to replace 0s in my data by forward filling from the previous non zero value along that row.

I was using the following code, but this replaces 0s from the row above instead of the same row:

```
df.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill')
```

In the code above, I am not able to specify the axis as 1.

The code below does exactly what I want, but only to NaN.

```
columns.fillna(method='ffill',axis=1)
```

```
A B C D
1 4 0 0
2 7 8 0
3 8 0 0
4 1 0 0
```

For example, in the above df, first row, I would like to replace the 0s with "4" and for the row below that, replace the 0 with 8.

Thanks

Comment: What about the 0 in Row 1 of Column D? Do you wish to replace that too?

Comment: yes, all of the 0s forward fill from the previous corresponding row.  applicable as such for the whole df.. so both 0s in the first row would be 4, respectively.

Comment: @MikeA It is a bit unclear what you want. Can you provide input and expected output? Thank you

Comment: One naive approach would be to convert zeros to NaNs and do the fillna with axis=1 as you mentioned

Comment: @Ehsan, I want to replace the 0s in each row by forward filling fa non zero value in the previous corresponding row.

Comment: @LazyCoder is right, try `df.replace(0, np.nan).ffill(axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

You can (1) `transpose` (2) `replace` and then (3) `transpose` again:

```
df.T.replace(0, method='ffill').T
#output:
    A   B   C   D
0   1   4   4   4
1   2   7   8   8
2   3   8   8   8
3   4   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
x=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3,4],'B':[4, 7, 8, 1],'C':[0, 8, 0, 0],'D':[0, 0, 0, 0]})
x_new=x.apply(lambda y: y.replace(to_replace=0, method='ffill'),axis=1)
x_new
>>  A   B   C   D
0   1   4   4   4
1   2   7   8   8
2   3   8   8   8
3   4   1   1   1
```